# Using mypy with await

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

Consider the following basic script using `asyncio`/`async`/`await`:

```
import asyncio
from typing import List

async def foo(x) -> int:
    await asyncio.sleep(x / 2)
    return x

async def main() -> List[int]:
    return await asyncio.gather(*(foo(i) for i in (1, 2, 3)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(asyncio.run(main()))
```

This runs find, printing `[1, 2, 3]`; `await asyncio.gather()` produces a `List[int]`.

However, mypy does not like this file; it raises:

> mypytest.py:9: error:
>
> Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Tuple[Any, ...]", variable has type "List[int]")

I'm assuming that's because of the [`asyncio.gather()` annotations](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/3c4141982e22aba6966daba5785d1ba959d7fc49/stdlib/3/asyncio/tasks.pyi#L34) in typeshed.

However, this is still a bit confusing from a user perspective.  **What can I be doing differently here to make mypy happy?  Why does this ambiguity exist?**

---

For what it's worth, there's not much on this in the [Typing async/await](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/more_types.html#async-and-await) part of the mypy docs.

Comment: looks like a bug in the type annotations, though perhaps an intentional hack to make multiple return values look normal (so you can decompose the return value) -- List doesn't support type args like that. probably worth making an issue on typeshed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This discrepancy was addressed in commit [412b9e7](https://github.com/python/typeshed/commit/412b9e74d557196dfcbe49dc443c17fbf503fd94) to the typeshed repository, which added a final `@overload` to account for the potential `List` result.

Answer (score -1):

Either annotate that line with `# type: ignore` or cast to `list` again:

```
return list(await asyncio.gather(*(foo(i) for i in (1, 2, 3))))
```

Comment: I'm aware I can just throw `# type: ignore` on something and make it go away.  That doesn't answer why `asyncio.gather()`'s annotation and the type of `await asyncio.gather()` are different

Comment: Not quite sure what your question asks then. I've answered what I know the answer to, "what can I do to make mypy happy"